openapi generated service always gives me a null filter
I have been generating the service with jaxrs-spec and currently with jaxrs-resteasy. The switch was done because resteasy returns wrong status according to yaml and resteasy is used in wildfly. I haven't got anything but null for the filter.
This is how the specification looks like.
    get:
      operationId: getMessageByFilter
      description: Get a specific message by filter option (messageStatus, creationDateTime, recipientAttention.subOrganization.extension, senderAttention.subOrganization.extension). This operation always excludes digitalDocument
      tags:
        - Message life cycle
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          description: "The filter query parameter family is reserved to be used as the basis for any filtering of strategy. ?Filter[attribute]=value"
          example: '?filter[recipientAttention.subOrganization.extension]=sdk:inkorg001:0203:inera.se'
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              'recipientAttention.subOrganization.extension':
                type: string
              'senderAttention.subOrganization.extension':
                type: string
              messageStatus:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/messageStatusDef"
              creationDateTimeStart:
                type: string
                format: date-time
              creationDateTimeStop:
                type: string
                format: date-time
          style: deepObject
          allowReserved: true
...

The service gets generated just fine.
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "Get a specific message by filter option (messageStatus, creationDateTime, recipientAttention.subOrganization.extension, senderAttention.subOrganization.extension). This operation always excludes digitalDocument", response = OutputArrayData.class, authorizations = {
        @io.swagger.annotations.Authorization(value = "message_auth", scopes = {
            @io.swagger.annotations.AuthorizationScope(scope = "urn:sdk.api:getMessageByFilter", description = "get a message by filter")
        })
    }, tags={ "Message life cycle", })
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses(value = { 
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = OutputArrayData.class),
        
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "BadRequest", response = Events.class),
        
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = Void.class),
        
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not found.", response = Void.class) })
    public Response getMessageByFilter( @QueryParam("filter") GetMessageByFilterFilterParameter filter,@Context SecurityContext securityContext)
    throws NotFoundException {
        return service.getMessageByFilter(filter,securityContext);
    }

Except that no matter what I send the filter is always null.
I have added ParamConvertProvider that returns an ParamConverter but there is no call the ParamConverterProvider since I changed to resteasy. There has never been a call to the provider with the filter class.
This is the ParamConverterProvider. Does not get called to get a "filter" converter.
@Provider
public class SdkApiParameterConverter implements ParamConverterProvider
{
    private GetByFilterParamConverter converter;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations)
    {
        if (aClass.isAssignableFrom(GetMessageByFilterFilterParameter.class))
        {
            if (converter == null)
            {
                converter = new GetByFilterParamConverter();
            }
            return (ParamConverter<T>) converter;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

We are deploying on wildfly. That's why resteasy got choosen for us.
I personally think there is something wrong with the API specification. I just can't figure this out.

Is it a problem in the yaml file?
Is it some other thing I need to implement to git it to work?

For now I have solved it by getting my hands on the HttpServletRequest object and parsing the object from the query string.

What does your ParamConverProvider look like? Is it annotated with @Provider? What container are you running in, WildFly, Quarkus, Jetty?

Updated question with appServer and ParamConverterProvider code.

Interesting. I don't see why the ParamConverterProvider wouldn't be working. Do you see it being invoked?

No, I have had a breakpoint in it.

What version of WildFly are you using?
